# Geometric Explanation of Tamagawa Numbers

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, algebraic-geometry, measure-theory, differential-forms

Sometimes in order to understand a concept thoroughly we need to have a algebraic view ( in terms of equations ) and corresponding geometric view.

My interest always lies with understanding the Tamagawa Numbers from different view points. So to say something, I already know the algebraic version of Tamagawa numbers ( both local and global parts ) . It can be stated as follows "  the semisimple linear algebraic group $G$ over $\mathbb Q$, the Tamagawa number of $G$ (which is the standard terminology for the volume of $G(\mathbb Q)\setminus G(\mathbb A)$ with respect to Tamagawa measure) should be equal to $1$, and when $G$ is an elliptic curve rather than a linear group, there are many interesting things that happened, and which gave rise to a series of seminal works, and the Tamagawa numbers are widely used for tori ( by T.Ono ) , and also later the Birch and Swinnerton-Dyer found an analogue of the tamagawa number of elliptic curve ( anlogous to the work of T.Ono in defining the tamagawa numbers of Tori ) that played a central part in defining the Birch and Swinnerton-Dyer conjectures."

In terms of measure the Tamagawa Number can be defined as $$\large \tau=\rho(G)^{-1} |\Delta_k|^{-\large \frac{1}{2} \rm { dim } G } \prod_{\nu \ | \infty} \omega_{\nu}  \prod_{\mathfrak{p}} L_{\mathfrak{p}}(1,\chi_{G})\omega_{\mathfrak{p}}$$ where $\omega$ is the gauge form on $G$, $\chi_{G}$ is the character of the representation of the Galois group of $\bar{k}/k$ on the lattice $\widehat{G}$ and $\rho(G) = \lim_{ s \mapsto 1 } (s - 1)^{r} L(s, \chi_{G})$ , $\Delta_k$ be the
discriminant of $k/\mathbb{Q}$. And in some sense $$\large \prod_{\nu \ | \infty} \omega_{\nu}  \prod_{\mathfrak{p}} L_{\mathfrak{p}}(1,\chi_{G})\omega_{\mathfrak{p}}$$ can be taken as the Haar Measure on $G(\mathbb{A})$.

I am now very curious in hearing to alternate interpretations of Tamagawa Number in Geometric sense, as a intuitive way. If there is some geometric way of explaining what is the tamagawa number , and what impact does it give , I would be very happy in listening that. Please don't include the wikipedia article ( as I have read it already ).

P.S : I know the answer will express something related to the differential forms, but I am a bit confused.  If there is some other intuitive explanation , I would be very happy. Even any article that does this job will be fine.

Thank you.

Comment: I already know the differential geometric version of it.

Comment: By the way, have you posted the question on MathOverFlow? Per chance you could get better answers?

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/71044/intuition-behind-the-tamagawa-numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are my two cents: some references  [1](http://www.math.uwo.ca/~adhillon/papers/geotam.pdf) and [2](http://www.mathunion.org/ICM/ICM1966.1/Main/icm1966.1.0509.0511.ocr.pdf).

Comment: The first paper is the one, which I have already got after searching in google, and the second one I don't know frankly. But I assume that if I had not seen the google and searched about this, your articles might have helped me a lot. So , why to wait, I will award a bounty to it ( even though the answer completely satisfy my requirements, at-least I must thank you for your helping nature ). I will wait for some time, and see if some one can add something, or else I award the bounty to you, instead of wasting it.

Comment: Those were some easy $\geq 535$ points. =)

Comment: @Rasmus : Yes, but what to do, I didn't have any other alternative. No body cared to answer the question, so that was only the way, to save the bounty from getting wasted. At-least some body enjoy the reputation.

Comment: @Iyengar, sorry for the lateness. My answer was just to save the bounty from waste. I hope you found it useful. Thanks for the bounty.

Comment: None of the two links works... The first one is [_THE GEOMETRY OF TAMAGAWA NUMBERS OF CHEVALLEY GROUPS_](https://web.archive.org/web/20070331070412/www.math.uwo.ca/~adhillon/papers/geotam.pdf) by KAI BEHREND AND AJNEET DHILLON. The second one is [_On Tamagawa Numbers_](https://www.mathunion.org/fileadmin/ICM/Proceedings/ICM1966.1/ICM1966.1.ocr.pdf#page=509) by Takashi Ono.

Comment: Both links are obsolete!! :(